# How can I list objects with sort and created date using App engine php72?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to app engine and trying to list objects from storage.
Can you please help me with below?

I use php72

Below code correctly list objects. 
But how can I list objects with created date?
My requirement is to list objects in a table with created date one column and latest first.

```
Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$bucketNm ="abc";
$userFolder = "mfolder"
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketNm);
$options = ['prefix' => $userFolder];

     foreach ($bucket->objects($options) as $object) {

        echo $object->name();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found a way to get other info of the object.

$info = $object->info();

I'm going to add data in to a multidimensional array and sort from there.